# null pointer exception: scalar extension of a java class

Tags: java, scala, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm playing around with using Scala for my processing projects.

I've extended the [`Rect`](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/index.html?toxi/geom/Rect.html) class from [ToxicLibs](http://toxiclibs.org), but I'm getting a null pointer exception when I try to call [`rect(toxi.geom.Rect r)`](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/p5/toxi/processing/ToxiclibsSupport.html#rect%28toxi.geom.Rect%29) from within a method.

```
import toxi.processing.ToxiclibsSupport
import toxi.geom.{ Vec2D, Rect }

class Scope(x: Float, y: Float, width: Float, height: Float) extends Rect(x, y, width, height) {

  def this(r: Rect) {
    this(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height)
  }

  def draw(gfx: ToxiclibsSupport) {
    gfx.rect(this) // null pointer exception occurs here 
  }

}
```

This is the code that calls the `draw` method:

```
import processing.core.PApplet
import toxi.processing.ToxiclibsSupport
import toxi.geom.Rect

class ScalaP5Test extends PApplet {

  var gfx = new ToxiclibsSupport(this)

  override def setup() {
    size(1000, 800)
  }

  override def draw() {
    var scope = new Scope(100, 200, 400, 300)
    scope.draw(gfx) // draw called here
   }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Ahh, I got it. I changed the gfx initialisation to: `var gfx: ToxiclibsSupport = null` and added `gfx = new ToxiclibsSupport(this)` to `setup()`.

Comment: I already tried ;). I don't have enough points, so I can't answer myself until for another 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I got it:

```
class ScalaP5Test extends PApplet {

  var gfx = null

  override def setup() {
    gfx = ToxiclibsSupport(this)

    ...

  }

  ...

}
```

Then you can reuse the variable in other functions. I'm not sure if that's the best way, so if you have a better way, let me know!